# Adding Actions to Stage Root Inside of a ClickListener Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, clicklistener

**BACKGROUND:** I am developing a "Space Invaders" style game using LibGDX and Scene2D. The block of code below is part of a `OverlayStage` I have created which is rendered on top of the `GameStage` only when the `GameState` is `READY`, `PAUSED`, or `GAMEOVER`. Therefore, each time the `OverlayStage` is needed, the `addActions()` method below is called.

**PROBLEM:** My problem arises only with the case of the `PAUSED` GameState. (The Actions called in the `else` statement below work just fine) Ideally, I would like the `OverlayStage` to fade in and wait for the user to touch the screen (anywhere on screen) before fading out. However, when the Actions are added with the `ClickListener` below, the Screen does NOT fade but instead immediately disappears. I have done some debugging and realized that the `isDoneAction` is delayed by the amount of time I have assigned to `fadeOutAction` inside of `ActionUtils`. This, along with the fact that all of the other Actions below are working without issue in other parts of my code leads me to believe that the problem must be resulting from using the `ClickListener`.

I've been stuck on this for a few days now, and because it is so specific I cannot find any other resources. Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

```
private void addActions() {

    final Action isDoneAction = new Action() {
        @Override
        public boolean act(float delta) {
            isStageDone = true;
            return false;
        }   
    };

    if(state == GameState.PAUSED) {
        Action touchListenAction = new Action() {
            @Override
            public boolean act(float delta) {
                getRoot().addListener(new ClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                        getRoot().addAction(Actions.sequence(ActionUtils.fadeOutAction(),
                                            isDoneAction));
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }   
        };

        getRoot().addAction(Actions.sequence(ActionUtils.fadeInAction(), touchListenAction));
    }
    else {          
        getRoot().addAction(Actions.sequence(ActionUtils.fadeInAction(),
                            Actions.delay(MAX_SCREEN_TIME, ActionUtils.fadeOutAction()),
                            isDoneAction));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code for `ActionUtils.fadeOutAction()`?